# Issues with running a Demo Documentation

Tags: c++, win32gui

I am very new to c++ and i am looking at examples on how to use Win32 GUI

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/create-an-owner-drawn-combo-box#instructions

i copied and paste the complete code as shown (at the bottom) but it throws me with tons of errors (mostly undeclared identifier)

```
#define ID_BREAD 0
#define ID_DAIRY 1
#define ID_FRUIT 2
#define ID_MEAT  3

#define CX_BITMAP 24
#define CY_BITMAP 24

HBITMAP hbmBread;
HBITMAP hbmDairy;
HBITMAP hbmMeat;
HBITMAP hbmFruit;
HBITMAP hbmMask;

HBITMAP hbmIcon;

// Message handler for Square Meal dialog box.
INT_PTR CALLBACK FoodDlgProc(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, 
    LPARAM lParam)

    {
        UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
        TCHAR achTemp[256];
        HWND hwnd;

        switch (message)
        {
        case WM_INITDIALOG:
        // Call an application-defined function to load bitmap resources.
        if (!LoadIconBitmaps())
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, -1);
            break;
        }

        // Initialize the food groups combo box and select the first item.
        InitGroupList(hDlg);
        SendDlgItemMessage(hDlg, IDCOMBO, CB_SETCURSEL, 0, 0); 

        // Initialize the food list box and select the first item.
        InitFoodList(hDlg);
        SendDlgItemMessage(hDlg, IDLIST, LB_SETCURSEL, 0, 0); 

         return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_MEASUREITEM:
        {
        // Set the height of the items in the food groups combo box.
        LPMEASUREITEMSTRUCT lpmis = (LPMEASUREITEMSTRUCT) lParam;

        if (lpmis->itemHeight < CY_BITMAP + 2)
            lpmis->itemHeight = CY_BITMAP + 2;

        break;
        }

    case WM_DRAWITEM:
        {
        COLORREF clrBackground;
        COLORREF clrForeground;
        TEXTMETRIC tm;
        int x;
        int y;
        HRESULT hr;
        size_t cch;

        LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpdis = (LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT) lParam;

        if (lpdis->itemID == -1) // Empty item)
            break;

        // Get the food icon from the item data.
        hbmIcon = (HBITMAP) lpdis->itemData;

        // The colors depend on whether the item is selected.
        clrForeground = SetTextColor(lpdis->hDC, 
            GetSysColor(lpdis->itemState & ODS_SELECTED ?
            COLOR_HIGHLIGHTTEXT : COLOR_WINDOWTEXT));

        clrBackground = SetBkColor(lpdis->hDC, 
            GetSysColor(lpdis->itemState & ODS_SELECTED ?
            COLOR_HIGHLIGHT : COLOR_WINDOW));

        // Calculate the vertical and horizontal position.
        GetTextMetrics(lpdis->hDC, &tm);
        y = (lpdis->rcItem.bottom + lpdis->rcItem.top - tm.tmHeight) / 2;
        x = LOWORD(GetDialogBaseUnits()) / 4;

        // Get and display the text for the list item.
        SendMessage(lpdis->hwndItem, CB_GETLBTEXT,
            lpdis->itemID, (LPARAM) achTemp);

        hr = StringCchLength(achTemp, 256, &cch);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            // TODO: Write error handler.
        }

        ExtTextOut(lpdis->hDC, CX_BITMAP + 2 * x, y,
            ETO_CLIPPED | ETO_OPAQUE, &lpdis->rcItem,
            achTemp, (UINT)cch, NULL);

        // Restore the previous colors.
        SetTextColor(lpdis->hDC, clrForeground);
        SetBkColor(lpdis->hDC, clrBackground);

        //  Draw the food icon for the item. 
        HDC hdc = CreateCompatibleDC(lpdis->hDC); 
        if (hdc == NULL) 
            break; 

        SelectObject(hdc, hbmMask); 
        BitBlt(lpdis->hDC, x, lpdis->rcItem.top + 1, 
            CX_BITMAP, CY_BITMAP, hdc, 0, 0, SRCAND); 

        SelectObject(hdc, hbmIcon); 
        BitBlt(lpdis->hDC, x, lpdis->rcItem.top + 1, 
            CX_BITMAP, CY_BITMAP, hdc, 0, 0, SRCPAINT); 

        DeleteDC(hdc); 

        // If the item has the focus, draw the focus rectangle.
        if (lpdis->itemState & ODS_FOCUS)
            DrawFocusRect(lpdis->hDC, &lpdis->rcItem);

        break;
        }

    case WM_COMMAND:
            switch (LOWORD(wParam)) 
            { 
                case IDCOMBO: 
                    if (HIWORD(wParam) == CBN_SELENDOK) 
                    { 
                        InitFoodList(hDlg); 
                        SendDlgItemMessage(hDlg, IDLIST, 
                            LB_SETCURSEL, 0, 0); 
                    } 
                    break; 

                case IDLIST: 
                    if (HIWORD(wParam) != LBN_DBLCLK) 
                        break; 

                // For a double-click, process the OK case. 
                case IDOK: 

                    // Get the text for the selected list item. 
                    hwnd = GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDLIST); 

                    // Here it is assumed the text can fit into achTemp.
                    // If there is doubt, call LB_GETTEXTLENGTH first.
                    SendMessage(hwnd, LB_GETTEXT, 
                        SendMessage(hwnd, LB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0), 
                        (LPARAM) achTemp); 

                    // TODO: Do something with the selected text.

                    EndDialog(hDlg, 0); 
                    break; 

                case IDCANCEL: 
                    hwnd = GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDCOMBO); 
                    if (SendMessage(hwnd, CB_GETDROPPEDSTATE, 0, 0)) 
                        SendMessage(hwnd, CB_SHOWDROPDOWN, FALSE, 0); 
                    else EndDialog(hDlg, 0); 
            } 
            break; 

    case WM_DESTROY:

        // Call the application-defined function to free the bitmap resources.
        DeleteIconBitmaps();
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}

// Loads string resources and adds them as items to the drop-down list of
//   the food groups combo box. The bitmap handle of each item&#39;s icon is
//   stored as item data for easy access when the item needs to be drawn.
// 
void InitGroupList(HWND hDlg)
{
    TCHAR achTemp[256];
    DWORD dwIndex;

    // Get the handle of the food groups combo box.
    HWND hwndGroupsBox = GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDCOMBO);

    LoadString(hInst, IDS_BREAD, achTemp, sizeof(achTemp)/sizeof(TCHAR));
    dwIndex = SendMessage(hwndGroupsBox, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM) achTemp);
    SendMessage(hwndGroupsBox, CB_SETITEMDATA, dwIndex, (LPARAM) hbmBread);

    LoadString(hInst, IDS_DAIRY, achTemp, sizeof(achTemp)/sizeof(TCHAR)); 
    dwIndex = SendMessage(hwndGroupsBox, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM) achTemp);
    SendMessage(hwndGroupsBox, CB_SETITEMDATA, dwIndex, (LPARAM) hbmDairy);

    LoadString(hInst, IDS_FRUIT, achTemp, sizeof(achTemp)/sizeof(TCHAR));
    dwIndex = SendMessage(hwndGroupsBox, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM) achTemp);
    SendMessage(hwndGroupsBox, CB_SETITEMDATA, dwIndex, (LPARAM) hbmFruit); 

    LoadString(hInst, IDS_MEAT, achTemp, sizeof(achTemp)/sizeof(TCHAR)); 
    dwIndex = SendMessage(hwndGroupsBox, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM) achTemp);
    SendMessage(hwndGroupsBox, CB_SETITEMDATA, dwIndex, (LPARAM) hbmMeat);

    return;
}

// Fills the food list based on the selected item in the food groups
//   combo box.
void InitFoodList(HWND hDlg)
{
    TCHAR achTemp[256];

    HWND hwndGroupsBox = GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDCOMBO);
    HWND hwndFoodList = GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDLIST);

    // Clear the list contents.
    SendMessage(hwndFoodList, LB_RESETCONTENT, 0, 0);

    // Find out which food group is selected.
    int idFoodGroup = SendMessage(hwndGroupsBox, CB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0);

    switch (idFoodGroup)
    {
    case ID_BREAD:
        LoadString(hInst, IDS_OAT, achTemp, sizeof(achTemp)/sizeof(TCHAR));
        SendMessage(hwndFoodList, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM) achTemp);

        LoadString(hInst, IDS_WHEAT, achTemp, sizeof(achTemp)/sizeof(TCHAR));
        SendMessage(hwndFoodList, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM) achTemp);

        LoadString(hInst, IDS_RYE, achTemp, sizeof(achTemp)/sizeof(TCHAR));
        SendMessage(hwndFoodList, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM) achTemp);
        break;

    case ID_DAIRY:
        LoadString(hInst, IDS_CHEDDAR, achTemp, sizeof(achTemp)/sizeof(TCHAR));
        SendMessage(hwndFoodList, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM) achTemp);

        LoadString(hInst, IDS_MILK, achTemp, sizeof(achTemp)/sizeof(TCHAR));
        SendMessage(hwndFoodList, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM) achTemp);

        LoadString(hInst, IDS_PROCESSED, achTemp, sizeof(achTemp)/sizeof(TCHAR));
        SendMessage(hwndFoodList, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM) achTemp);

        LoadString(hInst, IDS_SWISS, achTemp, sizeof(achTemp)/sizeof(TCHAR));
        SendMessage(hwndFoodList, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM) achTemp);

        break;

    case ID_FRUIT:
        LoadString(hInst, IDS_APPLES, achTemp, sizeof(achTemp)/sizeof(TCHAR));
        SendMessage(hwndFoodList, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM) achTemp);

        LoadString(hInst, IDS_BANANAS, achTemp, sizeof(achTemp)/sizeof(TCHAR));
        SendMessage(hwndFoodList, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM) achTemp);

        LoadString(hInst, IDS_ORANGES, achTemp, sizeof(achTemp)/sizeof(TCHAR));
        SendMessage(hwndFoodList, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM) achTemp);

        break;

    case ID_MEAT:
        LoadString(hInst, IDS_BEEF, achTemp, sizeof(achTemp)/sizeof(TCHAR));
        SendMessage(hwndFoodList, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM) achTemp);

        LoadString(hInst, IDS_CHICKEN, achTemp, sizeof(achTemp)/sizeof(TCHAR));
        SendMessage(hwndFoodList, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM) achTemp);

        LoadString(hInst, IDS_PORK, achTemp, sizeof(achTemp)/sizeof(TCHAR));
        SendMessage(hwndFoodList, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM) achTemp);

        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    return;
}

// Loads the food icon bitmaps from the application resources.
//
BOOL LoadIconBitmaps(void)
{
    hbmBread = LoadBitmap(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BREAD));

    if (hbmBread != NULL)
         hbmDairy = LoadBitmap(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_DAIRY));

    if (hbmDairy != NULL)
         hbmMeat = LoadBitmap(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_MEAT));

    if (hbmMeat != NULL)
        hbmFruit = LoadBitmap(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_FRUIT));

    if (hbmFruit != NULL)
        hbmMask = LoadBitmap(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_MASK));

    if (hbmMask != NULL)
        return TRUE;

    return FALSE;
}

// Frees the icon bitmps.
//
void DeleteIconBitmaps(void)
{
    FreeResource(reinterpret_cast<HGLOBAL>(hbmBread));
    FreeResource(reinterpret_cast<HGLOBAL>(hbmDairy));
    FreeResource(reinterpret_cast<HGLOBAL>(hbmMeat));
    FreeResource(reinterpret_cast<HGLOBAL>(hbmFruit));
    FreeResource(reinterpret_cast<HGLOBAL>(hbmMask));
}
```

Can anyone share with me what am i missing out? Or how am I suppose to correctly run this to look at the output UI

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `#include windows.h>` at the top of the file to be able to use the Win32 API.

Comment: Yes i added #include <windows.h>
#include <winuser.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <sdkddkver.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> just to be safe but the IDS variables are still returning undeclared

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at MSDN you need to see what includes and libraries do you need. On your page its not there but for windows programs you need to `#include <Windows.h>`. If you are getting errors such as LNK2011 or LNK2019 there is a problem with linking things. What editor are you using? To learn about the Win32 API don't copy and paste.

Comment: I am using visual studio there’s a lot of IDs variables declare in the code that’s missing